# Java jar cannot find class on run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have created a simple `Java` program in `IntelliJ` ide. I used few libraries and when I try to export the jar as an artifact and run it from command line I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

Compiling & Running the program inside `IntelliJ` works great.

My project is configured as a `gradle` project with the following `build.gradle`:

```
group 'marianpavel.com'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.bastian-oppermann.de"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'de.btobastian.javacord:javacord:2.0.11'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13'
    compile 'de.btobastian.sdcf4j:sdcf4j-core:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.btobastian.sdcf4j:sdcf4j-javacord:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
}
```

I have exported the jar as followed: Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Jar -> From Module with dependencies -> Added the main source folder and all the libraries from library files, added a manifest and a main class and exported the jar.

I am trying to figure this out for days and I don't understand why it cant find the `class`.

Comment: The stacktrace says that you don't have guava in the classpath. Did you try to add it at runtime with the `-classpath` option?

Comment: Your program seems to depend on that libraries, i.e. you have to [add them to classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) when you try to run your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a misconception on your end.

Your project consists of **two** important parts:

1. Your own code
2. External libraries that your code is using

When you run your project within an IDE, and your project setup is correct, then **both** things are in your classpath.

But when you create a **JAR** for your project, it very much depends on your setup. Meaning: the "default" would be that a JAR created for your project **only** contains the "1." parts. Because you **do not want** that all external classes are added to "your" JAR in the first place.

So, to resolve that: when you want to run your program from your JAR on the command line, then you will need all those **external** JARs to be in your classpath as well! Because, as said: to run, you need both "1" and "2" parts to be present in the classpath.

Conclusion: you should check what gradle puts in the JAR it creates for you. I am pretty sure: that JAR only contains "1".

(and for the record, it is fine like that. it is possible to bundle everything into a single jar, but that will require work on your end)

Comment: It is ok if I put all the jar's that my project use in a separate folder and use that folder in the classpath ? Right now my libraries jar's are inside main jar.

Comment: I can't tell you what is right ;-) You have to figure how you want your JAR to look like. I think you can even include "dependencies" to other JARs in the META information of your JAR. In that case, you just need that directory in your classpath; and you list all required JARs in your own JAR. Alternatively, you have to list all **JAR file names** in your classpath! Or, in other words: you want to read gradle documentation to figure what the tool is doing; and how you can influence what it is doing!

Comment: You are very best sir :) I have exported all the jar's in the directory of the jar and added all the libraries manually in the classpath, now the jar runs correctly

Comment: Thank you very much. Glad I could help!